# Observable continues to retry subscription after catching error

Tags: c#, system.reactive

The below is code I encountered from a project I am working on, simpified as much as I can.

The ViewModel listens on a command (button press) which triggers `_subject.OnNext()`. It subscribes to `_subject` as below.  There is an extension method, OnError that catches exceptions.

What is happening is that the error is caught as expected but then the observable returned from `GetObservable` keeps retrying.  So I get output like the below non stop.  I am not understanding how OnError is working here.  Does `Catch` automatically resubscribe when returning a source?

---

**Output:**

```
SUBSCRIBED
System.Exception: ERROR
SUBSCRIBED
System.Exception: ERROR
SUBSCRIBED
System.Exception: ERROR
```

---

**Code:**

```
public ViewModel()
{
    _subject.Subscribe(_ => Save());
}

private void Save()
{
    GetObservable().OnError(ex => Debug.WriteLine(ex)).Subscribe();
}

private IObservable<Unit> GetObservable()
{
    return Observable.Create<Unit>(observer =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SUBSCRIBED");
        observer.OnNext(Unit.Default);
        observer.OnError(new Exception("ERROR"));
        observer.OnCompleted();
        return Disposable.Empty;
    }).Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
}
```

---

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<T> OnError<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<Exception> action)
    {
        IObservable<T> observable = null;
        observable = source.Catch<T, Exception>(ex =>
          {
              action(ex);
              return observable;
          });
        return observable;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Progman Sorry I wasn't clear.  I edited my question to remove what I want to do as for now I am mainly interested on the behavior I am seeing with the code I am showing.  The code and extension is what I encountered on a project I am working on so not sure why it is written the way it is.  Just trying to understand what is happening, ie. how it keeps retrying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Catch()` operator returns an observable, which is like "concatenating" the observable it is called on and the observable which is defined in the provided `Func<TException, IObservable<TSource>>` expression in case there was an exception. Check the marble diagram of the Catch operator from https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/catch.html:

[image]

As you see the result is "one" observable.

So in your case you get:

```
OnNext(Unit.Default)
```

and due to the exception the observable you are currently building. So basically you start from the top again. And this means you observable generates:

```
OnNext(Unit.Default)
OnNext(Unit.Default)
OnNext(Unit.Default)
OnNext(Unit.Default)
OnNext(Unit.Default)
...
```